Not able to run the webdriverIO test cases on ubuntu jenkins server getting browser is crashed message on console

I have written test cases using webdriverIO with cucumber and pushed everything on github and checked my local, it is working fine

I have configured Jenkins with github

Before that jenkins was configured in Ubuntu server machine and I have installed chrome and firefox browser

Run and check I am getting below error message.


Showing below error on wdio.conf.log file
2024-05-16T14:58:52.635Z INFO wdio-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter:

The 'r2024-05-16T14:58:53.182Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol

2024-05-16T14:58:53.185Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session

2024-05-16T14:58:53.186Z INFO webdriver: DATA
{
  capabilities: {
    alwaysMatch: {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
      'moz:firefoxOptions': [Object],
      'wdio:sharedStoreServicePort': 42997
    },
    firstMatch: [ {} ]
  },
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': { args: [Array] },
    'wdio:sharedStoreServicePort': 42997
  }
}

2024-05-16T14:58:54.003Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
Host info: host: 'ip-172-31-4-79', ip: '172.31.4.79'
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.8.0-1008-aws', java.version: '17.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.8.0-1008-aws', java.version: '17.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

2024-05-16T14:58:54.003Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 1/3

2024-05-16T14:58:54.003Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session

2024-05-16T14:58:54.004Z INFO webdriver: DATA
{
  capabilities: {
    alwaysMatch: {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
      'moz:firefoxOptions': [Object],
      'wdio:sharedStoreServicePort': 42997
    },
    firstMatch: [ {} ]
  },
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': { args: [Array] },
    'wdio:sharedStoreServicePort': 42997
  }
}

Locally it is working fine but it's not working on ubuntu server. I have tried firefox and chrome browser both are showing similar error.

Have you tried running the test in headless mode?

Yes, I tried it on headless mode..

ok, are the chrome and firefox drivers present in the path as well? Also, information on how you've installed the browser would be helpful.

@Techrookie89 I have installed chrome browser using wget like this wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb with sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb. and the path is /usr/bin/google-chrome

Ok, need one more info. I need you to locate the chromedriver binary path (mostly it would be under node_modules/chromedriver/bin. Once located I want you to share the output you get for executing ./chromedriver

@Techrookie89. Sorry for the late response. I have set same path and executed showing below error message. 2024-05-21T11:31:47.474Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
